# famo.us input surface type range min/max attributes

Tags: famo.us

I'm trying to set min max attributes for inputSurface of type range, but its not working. The generated input element doesn't have min/max attributes.

My code:

```js
  var moveDown = this.options.flyerSheetHeight + this.options.flyerItemHeight + 2;

  var downModifier = new StateModifier({
      transform: Transform.translate(0, moveDown, 0)
    });

    var flyerItemGenSurface = new InputSurface({
      size: [this.options.flyerSheetWidth, 5],
      type: 'range',
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      properties: {
        zIndex: 1,
      }
    });

    this.mainNode.add(downModifier).add(flyerItemGenSurface);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this!

```
var moveDown = this.options.flyerSheetHeight + this.options.flyerItemHeight + 2;

var downModifier = new StateModifier({
  transform: Transform.translate(0, moveDown, 0)
});

var flyerItemGenSurface = new InputSurface({
  size: [this.options.flyerSheetWidth, 5],
  type: 'range',
  properties: {
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  attributes: {
    min: 1,
    max: 10
  }
});

this.mainNode.add(downModifier).add(flyerItemGenSurface);
```

edit: woops

Comment: Then it would be polite to mark it as the answer and upvote if you can. :)